# Test a input without the WicketForm

Tags: forms, wicket-1.5, wicket-tester

I have panels that's create input fields and that are include in a form in another panel creating the form. My problem is that I don't see how to unit test my panel.

Let's say I have this java :

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
    public MyPanel(String id, IModel model) {
        super(id, model);
        TextField<String> test = new TextField<String>("test");
        test.add(new StringValidator.MaximumLengthValidator(5));
        add(test);
    }

}
```

And the html :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head></head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <p>
            <label wicket:for="test"> <wicket:message key="test" />
            </label> <input type="text" wicket:id="test" />
        </p>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make a unit test that can test my MaximumLengthValidator ?
Since the panel does not contains a form, I can't use directly the FormTester and the WicketTester does not seem to use the Validator.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it is best to override class `FormComponentPanel`, which is a subclass of the generic type `FormComponent<T>`. This means that you can treat your new component just like e.g. an instance of `TextField<String>`.

```
public class MyPanel extends FormComponentPanel<String>
```

As from my experience, it is best to test form components by a `FormTester` on the containing `Form`. You don't get the converted input, unless the form is submitted.

What you could do for being able to test without form submission, is add a behavior reacting on the Javascript 'onupdate' function by `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`, but then you would have to do read the input from Javascript and convert it yourself.

Thus my adivce:

1. Extend `FormComponentPanel`
2. Use `FormTester` to test your validators

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and didn't find a satisfying answer here, or anywhere else. The question was asked four years ago, but I found a solution and will share it, even though the person who asked have moved on long time ago, it might still help others.
I prefer to have small components and test them, and forms can be large and complex, and it will reflect in the test, if the form is in one file. But how to test?

**The trick is to give in and put your component in a form.**

I made a small component that is only accassable for tests (currently in my src/test/java folder, but I might move it to another module and depend have it imported with test scope if I need it in more moduels in the project). With this small help class I can test my different components that will be in a form, when the application runs, and that needs to be tested inside a form.

It is a workaround, but I feel like I and the framework met half way.

```
public class FormPanel extends Panel {

   private final Component iNeedToBeInAForm;

   public FormPanel(String id, IModel<?> model, Component iNeedToBeInAForm) {
      super(id, model);
      this.iNeedToBeInAForm = iNeedToBeInAForm;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onInitialize() {
      super.onInitialize();
      final Form form = new Form("form", getDefaultModel());
      form.add(iNeedToBeInAForm);
      add(form);
   }
}
```

and the html used with this is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>

<wicket:panel>

    <form wicket:id="form">

    <div  wicket:id="panel" id="panel">

    </div>
    </form>
</wicket:panel>

</body>
</html>
```

In the tests I use it like this:

```
panel = new MyPanel("panel", model);
tester.startComponentInPage(new FormPanel("id", model, panel));
final FormTester formTester = tester.newFormTester("id:form");
formTester.setValue("panel:" + MyPanel.id_BETA_BLOCKAD_DOSAGE_START_SELECT, DEFAULT.toString());
tester.executeAjaxEvent("id:form:panel:" + MyPanel.id_BETA_BLOCKAD_DOSAGE_START_SELECT, "onchange");

Result result = tester.isVisible("id:form:panel:" + MyPanel.id_BETA_BLOCKAD_DOSAGE_START_TEXT);
assertThat(result.wasFailed(), is(true));
```